# React Native find by id

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

I have big SVG file which I'm displaying. Each element has its own id. Also each element should be updated (for example change color). Elements should update one by one. Is there a way to get element by id in react native? State is not an option, because I have dynamic SVG.

Thanks.

Comment: State would be the best way to handle this. I guess you could write a method that looks through all children to find one with a specific id and then use `setNativeProps` to update the color. But that would be a fairly complicated implementation. I would opt for managing things within state first if you can

Comment: @JohnRuddell thanks for your answer. But how could I write a method to find children by id? Is there a react native method like getElementById in web?

Comment: No, not that I know of. finding nodes in react usually is with the react-dom package which you wouldn't have in react-native. You can just recursively look through a tree of nodes essentially, looking at each elements children until you get to the lowest most element.

Comment: If you want help writing up a solution you're going to need to post some code that produces the issue you're having so we can help fix it for you. This is a very vague question as it is